# A function with positive decreasing Taylor coefficients?

Tags: taylor-series

The function $\frac{x}{\ln(1-x)}$ has a Taylor series $-1+c_1x+c_2x^2+\cdots$ and I want to show $c_1>c_2>\cdots>0$. More generally, is there a result about how a function has positive Taylor coefficients or has decreasing Taylor coefficients?

Comment: I already found the recurrence relation $c_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n}c_1-\cdots -\frac{1}{2}c_{n-1}$ but it seems to be nothing.

Comment: The numbers appear to be the same as those tabulated at http://oeis.org/A002206 where there are many links and references (this does not address the more general question).

Answer (score 5):

We have
$$-\int_{-1}^0 {1\over {(z+1)^t }}dt={ {-z}\over{\log(1+z)}}, \ \ \ \int_{-2}^{-1}{1\over {(z+1)^t }}dt={{z(z+1)}\over{\log(1+z)}}, \ \ z>0$$
So the k-derivative of these functions is positive when k is even and negative  when k is odd.
So the coefficients of the Taylor series of ${z\over{\log(1-z)}},{{z^2-z}\over{\log(1-z)}}$ are positive, as desired.

Comment: Wow! Pretty elegant proof!